# AS forcing to use android SDK Build Tools 25.0.0 SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

Hi I am facing build version issue. When I run the app, it throws an error that,

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':Yampp'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

I need to use 23.0.3, but it's forcing to use 25.0.0. How to solve the strange issue?

Here are the Gradle files

**build.gradle Module**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.Yampp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.25.10.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

**build.gradle Project**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can upgrade the compileSdk, build tools, and Gradle itself without affecting the app code

Comment: and I'm in a new bad place for the past day because I'm seeing `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolFor<build-flavour>'.` and *nothing* I do can fix it ! Forcing me to move from 23.0.3 to 25.0.x has been a major inconvenience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':Yampp'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

Just upgrade build tools to 25.0.0 this doesn't affect the app behavior.

```
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much :-) @Gabriele Mariotti