# react-native + npm + gradle package update

Tags: npm, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am a beginner with `react-native`, and I keep getting errors like

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':react-native-camera'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
```

which is discussed in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928447/how-to-upgrade-android-studio-2-3-to-build-tools-25-to-fix-the-sdk-build-tools) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630119/as-forcing-to-use-android-sdk-build-tools-25-0-0-sdk-build-tools-revision-23-0), and the answer is to edit `build.gradle` for the dependency (in this example `react-native-camera`) to set

```
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
```

This works, but it requires a lot of manual intervention as the number of dependencies grows. Is there a way to automatically get these changes handled by npm when it updates the packages?

Comment: I get the same error message everytime I run `npm install` on our React Native project.

Answer (score 0):

Install the SDK Build Tools 25 ?

Comment: if my understanding of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447687/check-android-developer-tools-version-command-line is correct, then I already have it installed.